# Время генерации страницы фреймворком Kohana 3.2

Tags: framework, php, kohana

Сайт работает на локальном хосте. Данные смотрю через Kohana_Profiler.

Время генерации стартовой страницы hello, world! - 0.5 сек., простая страница с оформлением  0,8-1 сек.

Это нормально для данного фреймворка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну у меня проект, на Кохане, более-менее не маленький,на VDS за 1 секунду формирует и отдаёт страницу. Так что я думаю для локалхоста - нормально.

Comment: Я перенес сайт на Kohana, поэтому сравниваю чистый php и фреймворк.
На чистом php страница формируется за 0,03 сек, против 1 сек. на фреймворке.

Comment: @DDD - вероятнее всего вы что-то делаете не так

Answer (score 0):

Kohana довольно шустро работает при прямо написанном коде. Роль железа тоже немаловажна. Опять же нужно смотреть сколько у вас моделей ORM и как устроена БД, может она перегружена запросами, что занимает лишнее время.

А вообще, умные книги по юзабилити интерфейсов говорят, что страница должна отдаваться пользователю примерно за 3 секунды, мол, если больше, то "томительное ожидание", меньше - "не понимает а ткнул ли на ссылку и совершился ли переход".

Comment: Запрос к БД занимает 0,003 сек, все остальное время Request и Find_file

Comment: @kemerov4anin - имеется введу не тупой HTML, а страница в целом, т.е. - картинки, js, css etc. Соответственно вы пишите о "немного" других вещах. В среднем, при ровном коде, генерация страницы должна занимать примерно 5-15% времени загрузки всей страницы.

Answer (score 0):

При определённом стечении обстоятельств на локальном хосте под виндой скорость работы Apache может быть гораздо медленнее, чем на среднестатическом хостинге :)